# MediaWiki: Hiding certain HTML elements for non-logged-in users

Tags: html, php, javascript, links, mediawiki

In a MediaWiki-based non-communal website there are some HTML elements that should be presented only for logged-in-users (an administration menu or some of its links).

Usually if I want to hide something for a certain group of users like anonymous users I browse into the website when logged-out, and then take a `<body>` CSS ID or Class like `#anonymous-user` to create some condition like this:

```
#anonymous-user .administration-menu {display: none}
```

I tried to search for a `<body>` CSS ID or Class that I could utilize to hide things for anonymous users in MediaWiki but found none.

How could I create one myself?

Comment: All `display:none` is doing is hiding a section of a page if a user is using your stylesheet, which they can turn off. If there are links only for admins that is a very bad way of operating. Instead you should have a server variable set when a user is logged in, test for that, and only if it's set then create in PHP the section containing the links. MediaWiki tests for logged in users with `if ( $user->isLoggedIn() ) {`, see eg [user.php](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/ec7e434a4ec406ffb751a04b5084c552d7ac279f/includes/user/User.php).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to adjust the user/group permissions behind the scenes. Here is the guide the default user and group permissions that are installed on the stock API.

[MediaWiki Help:User rights and groups](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:User_rights_and_groups)

You may have to work in reverse with the stock permissions by hiding / restricting features to the “all” group then allowing the features to the “users” and “administrators” list.